# Prolog read input without full stop

Tags: command, prolog

I am currently programming a small text-based adventure game in SWI-Prolog. Hence, the user will have to give commands like "goto(room)" or "goto room".

However the problem is that you always have to finish the command with a full stop, i.e.
"goto(room)." instead of "goto(room). This is not very user-friendly.

I have a predicate that reads a command and then executes the input. How can I automatically add the full stop if there is none (if there already is one the input should just be executed)?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Volker

Comment: have you tried checking if it doesn't have a full stop then appending one to it?

Comment: Why don't you write a predicate that will get(read) an input string in your case the "goto room" or "goto(room)" , then parse the string , and based on the result from parsing, call the appropriate predicate ( goto(room). in your case ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you are using `read/1` or some variation; this is supposed to be used to read valid prolog terms (and that's why you need a full-stop).

The solution would be to parse the input on your own (check [primitive char io](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.18%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/chario.html%27%29%29), [read utilities](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.24%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/readutil.html%27%29%29) and [io in general](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.16%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29) (you will probably need just the read utilities though)) and then [convert](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.21%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipatom.html%27%29%29) it to a term.

Additionally, you can create a small natural language with DCGs and use; for example the user could just write `goto room` instead of `goto(room)`.

On the other hand, I personally don't think that having to skip a full-stop it will be a lot more user friendly if they have to type prolog terms anyway.